# Suggestion: Using Sci-TLDR in SO for aggregating questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

The Allen institute made this:
https://scitldr.apps.allenai.org/

It has this GitHub repo:
https://github.com/allenai/scitldr

It boils texts down, with some work, to their essentials.

The license is apache 2.0, which means you can wrap it in other stuff.
https://github.com/allenai/scitldr/blob/master/LICENSE

Suggestion: you might consider integrating it here, with your similar question detection, to determine whether the body of the question has a similar tldr summary to another, existing question.

Comment: Would we need a new queue Suggested duplicates? Or would they go into LQP with a comment? Or is the suggestion to close them as a duplicate and let the OP argue their case that it is not a duplicate?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus - I remember thinking the same thing about the game of "go" in 2014.  It would be really convenient if DeepMind or equivalent took up the gauntlet and make (then open sourced) a great try there.

Comment: @EngrStudent: Go, Chess, ... and other games are closed worlds, however complicated ... understanding human text is far from!